# http request won't execute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a real noob in JS and Node and am trying to render a JADE view from JSON received from a REST API. When i run the http.request as a standalone it works just fine, but when i start adding modules and the render stamens, I cannot get the http request function to execute.

When i run it in debug it just skips to the end statement. i cannot figure out why.

any help would be really appreciated TIA.

```js
var http = require('http');

module.exports = function() {

    var options = {
        host: '41.193.214.130',
        port: 2510,
        path: '/eiftidemo/clt_list',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var clientsDatag;

    http.request(options, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        //none of these statemnst excecute

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var clientsData = JSON.parse(body);

            var clientsDatag = clientsData;
            // this stament doesn't execute either
            debugger;

        });
    }).end();
    debugger;
    res.render('listlxr', {
        details: clientsDatag
    });
};
```

here is the calling script:

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var tweetList = require('./tweet-list');
var clientList = require('./lxr-clients')
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/get_tweets', function(req, res) {
    var screen_name = req.body.handle;

    var tweets = tweetList(res, screen_name);
});

app.get('/get_clients', function(req, res) {

    var clientd = clientList(res, req);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Our App is running at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

many thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/get_clients', function(req, res) {

    var options = {
        host: '41.193.214.130',
        port: 2510,
        path: '/eiftidemo/clt_list',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(details) {
        res.render('listlxr', {
            details: details
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: A little explanation would help the OP understand why they can't do what they were doing (async response) and would make your answer a lot better answer.  You might also still preserve the external module that the OP had the code in.

Comment: i think this means adding the code into the calling script directly. ill try that and many thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an error-handler and see if you get anything there:

```
var request= http.request(options, function(res) {...});

request.on('error', function(err){
     // Handle error
});
```